# Log file not rolling automatically in jetty 9.3.16

Tags: java, jetty

Currently, I am moving the server and upgrade the jetty from 9.2 to 9.3. But unfortunately, I found that the logging file doesn't role automatically in 9.3, however, it was working fine in jetty 9.2.

The file name only changed when I restart the server.

I am thinking, do I miss some config in jetty 9.3? Thanks.

1, In `9.3.16`

[image]

[image]

2, Previously in jetty `9.2`.
[image]

My `log4j2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<configuration status="OFF">  
  <appenders>  
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">  
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} [%M](%L) - %msg%n"/>  
    </Console>  
    <File name="log" fileName="log/test.log" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %class{36} %L %M - %msg%xEx%n"/>
    </File>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="log/app.log"
                 filePattern="log/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss z} %-5level %class{36} %L %M - %msg%xEx%n"/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50MB"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </appenders>  
  <loggers>
    <root level="info">  
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
      <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </root>  
  </loggers>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: How is your logging configured? Can you share the settings of your `${jetty.home}/resources/jetty-logging.properties` or `{jetty.base}/start.ini` (or `{$jetty.base}/start.d/logging.ini`) file? For the latter, what do you have `jetty.logging.append` set to?

Comment: Dear @Walkerwatch,

All these configurations are default, and didn't set `jetty.logging.append`.

Attached my `log4g2.xml` file.

Comment: you are not using log4j2.xml in those examples you pasted.  the `*_stderrout.log` files are from jetty's `console-capture` (called in 9.4.x) or `jetty-logging` (prior to 9.4.x).  that means you are likely caught in the bug for issue https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1357

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, thanks, guess you are right, I switched it back to jetty 9.3.14 and it worked correctly.

Comment: Note: 9.3.17 (due out this week) will have it fixed.